# Slide control like lock screen objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to create swiping effect like lock screen of iOS 7. That means if I have two view controllers, I want to swipe the first to show the second. I can do it by using UISwipeGestureRecognizer. However, I don't know how to implement sliding effect like when swiping lock screen. Please help me give some clues

Answer (score 1):

Apple tell you how they implemented the lock screen in one of their WWDC videos.

Check out "Exploring Scroll Views on iOS 7" under

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: Thanks, but can u give me the direct link? there are a lot of videos there and I cannot check every one.

Comment: Um, it's the one called "Exploring Scroll Views on iOS 7" as I said and they're in alphabetical order (click on the description column header if not and then they will be) so you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a UIPanGestureRecognizer for this particular use case.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView:

Basically you set the views for your two UIViewControllers frames so the first on is visible and the other one is on the side of it (off screen) then you use the action method you specified to move the views the appropriate amount like so

```
CGPoint movedAmount = panningLastTouchLocation.x - [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x;
CGRect frame1 = firstVC.view.frame;
CGRect frame2 = secondVC.view.frame;

frame1.x -= movedAmount;
frame2.x -= movedAmount;

firstVC.view.frame = frame1;
secondVC.view.frame = frame2;
panningLastTouchLocation = [panner locationInView:self.view];
```

basically if they swipe far enough over then just animate the view the rest of the way to go to the new view

Comment: Thanks, I solved by setting my paging mode in the UIScrollView, but your solution makes sense.